# How can I change the spacing for specific words in powerpoint, using vba?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, spacing

What I try to do is write in vba a sub that goes through all text/ shape boxes, find specific words/ chars in a word and changes the space between, using the 'spacing' method.
for some reason, I keep getting the same error, which I cannot figure how to solve. 
for example, let's say I have a the string **RLgsfub**, and i have a list of words **(RF,gs,Fg)**.
the sub will find the **gs** and change the spacing.

I've tried to combine a couple of things, but I can't figure out why it still doesn't work.
this is the last code, when setting it to **.Font.Bold = true** , it works, but here with **.Font2.spacing = 2** it doesn't.
I've tried changing the **shp.TextFrame.TextRange** to **shp.TextFrame2.TextRange** but still doesn't work.

```
Sub spacing():
For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            Set txtRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
            Set foundText = txtRng.Find(FindWhat:="CompanyX")
            Do While Not (foundText Is Nothing)
                With foundText
                    .Font2.spacing = 0
                    Set foundText = _
                        txtRng.Find(FindWhat:="CompanyX", _
                        After:=.Start + .Length - 1)
                End With
            Loop
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

other codes i tried using:

**this one is working:**

```
Sub use()

Dim s As Slide
Dim shp As Shape


For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides

    For Each shp In s.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            With shp
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.spacing = 24
        End If
    Next shp

Next s
End Sub
```

**this one doesn't work:**

```
Sub HighlightKeywords()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim txtRng As TextRange, rngFound As TextRange2
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim TargetList

    '~~>  Array of terms to search for
    TargetList = Array("keyword", "second", "third", "etc")

    '~~> Loop through each slide
    For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
        '~~> Loop through each shape
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            '~~> Check if it has text
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                Set txtRng = shp.TextFrame2.TextRange

                For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)
                    '~~> Find the text
                    Set rngFound = txtRng.Find(TargetList(i))

                    '~~~> If found
                    Do While Not rngFound Is Nothing
                        '~~> Set the marker so that the next find starts from here
                        n = rngFound.Start + 1
                        '~~> Chnage attributes
                        With rngFound.Font
                        .spacing = -24
                            '~~> Find Next instance
                            Set rngFound = txtRng.Find(TargetList(i), n)
                        End With
                    Loop
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually, this is what worked for me:
(I've mixed a couple of ideas, not sure it's written in the best and shortest way - but it works :)

```
  Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim txtRng As TextRange, rngFound As TextRange2
Dim j As Long, n As Long
Dim TargetList

'~~>  Array of terms to search for
TargetList = Array("Uf", "uf", "nU", "Nu", "Bf", "NuF", "nH", "Nh", "bF", "nUf", "Jk", "jK")

'~~> Loop through each slide
For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    '~~> Loop through each word
        For j = 0 To UBound(TargetList)
            Call changeFont(CStr(TargetList(j)))
        Next
Next
```

And the second part:

```
Sub changeFont(word As String)

Dim oPresentation   As Presentation
Dim oSlide          As Slide
Dim oShape          As Shape
Dim stringSearched  As String
Dim wordPos As Long
Dim wordLen As Long

stringSearched = word
wordLen = Len(stringSearched)

'all opened presentations
For Each oPresentation In Presentations
    'all slide in them
    For Each oSlide In oPresentation.Slides
        'all shapes (anything)
        For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
            'only those that contain text
            If oShape.HasTextFrame Then
                wordPos = InStr(oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, stringSearched)
                If wordPos > 0 Then
                    'here you need to define where the text ends and start
                    oShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(InStr(oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, stringSearched), Len(stringSearched)).Font.Spacing = -5
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last code has several flaws, but the problem is not setting the spacing. `txtRng` should be of type `TextRange2`, the spacing should probably be not negative (although that works), but main problem is that it ends up in an endless loop when searching for a word.

I have split your code and changed the logic how the words are found in the shape: I copy the text into a string variable to do the search for a word, use the hit to format the shape text and replace the found word in the copied string by a dummy so it's easy find the next occurrence of the word.

The inner loop of the calling routine can be reduced to

```
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)
                Call MarkCharacters(shp.TextFrame2.TextRange, CStr(TargetList(i)))
            Next
        End If
```

and the new sub looks like

```
Sub MarkCharacters(txtRng As TextRange2, word As String)

    Dim s As String, wordPos As Long, wordLen As Long
    s = txtRng.Text
    wordLen = Len(word)

    wordPos = InStr(s, word)
    Do While wordPos > 0
        DoEvents
        txtRng.Characters(p, wordLen).Font.Spacing = 24
        ' Replace found word with "x"
        s = Left(s, wordPos - 1) _
          & String(wordLen, "x") _
          & Mid(s, wordPos + l)
        wordPos = InStr(s, word)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it, but (if i did everything right) i get "the index into the specified collection is out of bounds" on " txtRng.Characters(p, wordLen).Font.Spacing = 0"

Comment: Check the values of `p` and `wordLen` in the debugger when this happens.